# SQL Server: querying from string xml value

Tags: sql-server, xml, xquery, osb

I need to join some XML data with relational data and to do it in a pure non-procedural SQL Server.

I may pass the desired xml as a `(n)varchar` or even lexical parameter.

Since all the examples I've come across declare a variable of XML type, I expected that inline casting to XML might help:

```
SELECT T.c.value('.','int') AS result  
FROM CAST(N'<Root><row id="1"><name>Larry</name><oflw>some text</oflw></row><row id="2"><name>moe</name></row><row id="3" /></Root>' AS XML).nodes('/Root/row/@id') T(c)
```

But I'm getting an "Incorrect syntax" error. I'm from Oracle so might have missed something obvious.

Is it possible to get a result set from string representation of xml in this way? Any other options to join relational data with the **external** xml?

The actual task is to enrich the passed xml with with relational table data and return the result either as xml or result set.

I am restricted by:

1. High latency
2. Tag fn-bea:execute-sql (for those in the know)

The table has a field that exactly matches value is in xml
The number of rows - up to n000, both in table and xml

Any other ideas are also welcome

Comment: You have to wrap the cast thing into sub query and then you can use the nodes function on the column from the subquery

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question as text, no images.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky the question was related to querying from xml string passed as a query parameter, no data setup is needed for this. Once this query is ready I know what to do next

Comment: @siggemannen Could you elaborate please? The following also doesn't work: 
```SELECT T.c.value('.','int') AS result  
FROM 
(select xmldata.a.nodes('/Root/row/@id') T(c) 
   from 
   (select CAST(N'<Root>
    <row id="1">
        <name>Larry</name>
        <oflw>some text</oflw>
    </row>
    <row id="2">
        <name>moe</name>
    </row>
    <row id="3"/>
</Root>' AS XML) a 
    ) xmldata
)```

Comment: Try select c.value('@id', 'int')
from     (
 select CAST(N'<Root><row id="1"><name>Larry</name><oflw>some text</oflw></row><row id="2"><name>moe</name></row><row id="3"/></Root>' AS XML) a     
 ) x
cross apply x.a.nodes('Root/row') T(c)

Comment: You wrapped too much :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a conceptual example how to convert XML into rectangular (row and columns) format.

After that it is very easy to join the result set with any table(s).

> The actual task is to enrich the passed xml with with relational table
> data and return the result either as xml or result set.

It is possible, but you need to be specific by providing a **minimal reproducible example**: ##1-4.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, city VARCHAR(20));
INSERT @tbl (city) VALUES
('Miami'),
('Orlando');

DECLARE @xml XML = 
N'<Root>
    <row id="1">
        <name>Larry</name>
        <oflw>some text</oflw>
    </row>
    <row id="2">
        <name>moe</name>
    </row>
    <row id="3"/>
</Root>';
-- DDL and sample data population, end

;WITH rs AS
(
    SELECT c.value('@id','int') AS id  
        , c.value('(name/text())[1]','VARCHAR(20)') AS [name]
        , c.value('(oflw/text())[1]','VARCHAR(20)') AS oflw  
    FROM @xml.nodes('/Root/row') AS t(c)
)
SELECT rs.*, t.city
FROM rs LEFT OUTER JOIN @tbl AS t ON t.ID = rs.id;
```

**SQL #2**

```
;WITH rs AS
(
    SELECT TRY_CAST(N'<Root>
            <row id="1">
                <name>Larry</name>
                <oflw>some text</oflw>
            </row>
            <row id="2">
                <name>moe</name>
            </row>
            <row id="3"/>
        </Root>' AS XML) AS xmldata
)
SELECT c.value('@id','int') AS id  
        , c.value('(name/text())[1]','VARCHAR(20)') AS [name]
        , c.value('(oflw/text())[1]','VARCHAR(20)') AS oflw  
FROM rs
CROSS APPLY xmldata.nodes('/Root/row') AS t(c);
```

**Output**

| id | name | oflw | city |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Larry | some text | Miami |
| 2 | moe | NULL | Orlando |
| 3 | NULL | NULL | NULL |

Comment: I should have emphasized **non-procedural**: for some reason this .nodes('/Root/row') doesn't work with the xml casted inline from string for me.

Comment: I updated the answer with the **SQL #2**, check it out.